# java: illegal start of expression - method parameters

Tags: java, string, list, bufferedreader

I use method for create and retrieves the list of entries with existing file using the instance.

My goal is to mute all actions performed by check Counter into several independent methods exemple first action "read".
I have other file for exemple result ( action count, sort..)

My method have  "illegal start of expression" in position "(parameter).
I'm stuck on using parameter with List !

```java
public class CheckCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ReadSymptomDataFromFile readerFile = new ReadSymptomDataFromFile("Pro/heath.text");

        public List<String>  getSymptoms() {

    
        List<String> symptom = readerFile.GetSymptoms();
        System.out.println(symptom);
    }
}
```

```
// file interface
   public interface ISymptomReader {

    List<String> GetSymptoms ();    
}
```

Comment: You need to give a name to that String parameter.

Comment: And then move the method outside the `main` method, moving it into `ReadSymptomDataFromFile` if that's not where this code is declared, and then give it an actual implementation, and then call it as `getSymptoms()` rather than `GetSymptoms()`... basically, there's a lot wrong here.

Comment: What is the error you don't understand and what behavior do you expect, that you are not observing currently?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, I update in my description. My goal is to mute all actions performed by check Counter into several independent methods. So I'm not sure I must move this method.

Comment: @LinFelix I want my method (get)to be able to read the file correctly, the file outside the mtehod is done correctly but My goal is to mute all actions performed by check Counter into several independent methods( exemple read, count, write... for the futur. And my method does not display an array in my console.

Comment: "So I'm not sure I must move this method." Well you definitely need to stop trying to declare one method within another method, which is what you're currently trying to do... I'd also strongly advise you to follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you only specified the type of the parameter and no name, thus creating a syntax error.

Comment: it'd be nice if you could give an example for clarity

Comment: @BagusTesa exemple with more code ?